# Where can I see my total Amazon S3 usage?

Tags: user-accounts, amazon-s3

I don't seem to be able to find a total amount of data I have stored in Amazon S3.

Total per bucket is okay, entire total also, and both would be best.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

Go to aws.amazon.com and click Account > Usage Reports

After signing in, select Amazon Simple Storage Service from the Service drop down and then select TimedStorage-ByteHrs from the Usage Types drop down. Select the period of time you want to be reported and use the buttons at the bottom to download the report.

The usage report gives a storage total for each bucket and each day, which is necessary to bill properly for additions and deletions. If all you need is the current total, just select a custom date range that includes only yesterday. If you download in CSV format it should be an easy matter to open the file in a spreadsheet application and sum the storage totals for all the buckets.

Comment: Oh right, my brain didn't even register the "Account" link! I thought everything took place in the management console... Anyway, thanks for the answer

Comment: And: these are Byte-Hours, not Bytes. You will have to divide by 24 to see the size

Comment: The report has moved. Direct link: https://portal.aws.amazon.com/gp/aws/developer/account/index.html?action=usage-report Or click Reports > AWS Usage Report.

Comment: @jfoucher It's not your fault you wouldn't think to look there.  Most of the AWS interface isn't exactly intuitive or consistent.

Answer (score 5):

Here's my [HowTo explaining how to parse S3 Usage Report](http://blog.nuxi.pl/2015/aws-tip-of-the-day-get-s3-disk-usage-per-bucket.html)  using bash one liner to get readable results.

```
cat report.csv | awk -F, '{printf "%.2f GB %s %s \n", $7/(1024**3 )/24, $4, $2}' | sort -n
```

Comment: Worked great for me.

Comment: Link is broken.

Answer (score 4):

You can now view the size of each S3 bucket directly in the console.  Click on the Amazon S3 ->  -> Management -> Metrics.

Comment: I just see "No metrics are currently available for Storage."

Answer (score 1):

Why can't you use your bill to get that number ?   Is that not what shows up in the detail section of the Amazon Simple Storage Service TimedSTorage-ByteHrs section?  It breaks it down by total size of stored object (<1TB, 1-50TB, 50+ ...et.c.) but you can do simple math then.

Answer (score 1):

An awesome solution is to use [S3Stat solutio](https://www.s3stat.com/)n which provides very nice reports and not free, but affordable.

A sample: 
[image]

Comment: This reads like an advertisement. Can you address how it directly answers the question?

Comment: I need to pay a third party $120 per year to see something that Amazon should include by default. Backblaze B2 has the nice graphs and when I'm using s3 instead I have the impression it's designed for "don't worry about the usage, you can see it when you will get the expensive bill at the end of the month"

Answer (score 0):

This is a follow on to Darren Kraker's answer (Amazon S3 -> [your bucket] -> Management -> Metrics) and Martin Eden's comment to say that I too was getting the "No metrics are currently available for Storage" when I first checked the Metrics panel on one of my buckets. Subsequently though, I checked several of my other buckets and got the data I was looking for. The difference? The buckets which had the info available only contained Standard class storage objects, whereas the first bucket I checked, the one with "no metrics... currently available" contained both Standard glass and Glacier objects. I am guessing that the Metrics panel cannot yet accurately tabulate the two separately, hence the "unavailable" message.